# How to copy pdf file to Books using File manager?

Tags: pdf, files.app

I have many pdf books in iCloud, now I wanna read it with Books application, according to https://support.apple.com/en-qa/HT205751, It said can `Tap the share button and Tap copy to Books`. But When I using Files to share the pdf file, there is only `Open in Books` avaliable, there is no `Copy to Books` avaliable:[image]

Comment: After you open in Books can you then close the book and re open it? Make a copy of the book on your desktop and delete it from iCloud. Does that book you opened in Books **still* open in books?

Comment: yea, I figured that out after entering the comment. I meant to delete it but got wrapped up trying to answer the question.  I have deleted my silly comment.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the  PDF file of interest on your iPhone or iPad and tap on it to open it.. Go to the share icon at the top and click it. A pane opens and on the 2nd row of options, you'll see options like AirDrop, Messages, Mail, and others. Slide this row to the left and at the end of that row you'll see an option for "More". Click on that option. This brings up a new menu and you should scroll down this menu to the option "Open in Book". Click on this option. Your PDF will be displayed using Books. Tap on the page that is displayed on your screen and you'll get another share icon at the top of the display. Click on this share icon and on the panel that opens is an option to Copy to Books. Click this. Now a copy of the PDF is saved in Books.

Comment: I accidentally hit the submit button twice. so I just deleted an answer and made one small change.  Thanks for the advice about breaking up the answer. i agree.  I don't see where he has an iPhone or iPad,

Comment: The image is a screenshot from an iPhone.